# Does Chabauty-Coleman method give an algorithm for finding rational points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points, birch-swinnerton-dyer

Let $X$ be a curve of genus $g\geq 2$ over a number field $K$. If $\mathrm{rk} \,\mathrm{Jac}\, X$ is less than $g$ there is a $p$-adic method of bounding $\# X(K)$ due to Chabauty and Coleman (see http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/chabauty.pdf).

> Does this method give an algorithm for computing $X(K)$ (say, their coordinates)?

I agree to assume BSD and finitness of Shafarevich-Tate group.

Trying to transform their proof to an algorithm, I met the following bottlenecks. First, we need to compute $\log \overline{\mathrm{Jac}(K)}$ (bar means $p$-adic closure) in order to obtain a $1$-form whose integral will vanish on rational points, which is weaker than computing $\mathrm{Jac}(K)$ but I still do not know any non-conjectural algorithms.

Next, the proof requires choosing base points in each residue class and I do not know how to find them algorithmically. Maybe, a solution can be obtained by extending the base field to where it is easy to find a base point.

Finally, we need an argument for computing zeroes of $p$-adic analytic functions. There is an argument, à la [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma), for computing zeroes sign-by-sign, which probably terminates if we search for points over number fields, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conjecturally, yes. Check out Section 4.4 of [this paper](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/schrift.html#AG31) by Nils Bruin and myself.

The point is to combine Chabauty-Coleman with the "Mordell-Weil Sieve". 
In the following, I will assume for simplicity that the Jacobian of your 
curve $X$ is simple and that $K = \mathbb Q$. I will also assume that
one rational point $P_0$ on $X$ is known, which we use to embed
$X$ into $J = \operatorname{Jac} X$.

In any case, assuming finiteness of Sha (say), one can in principle determine the rank $r$ of $J(\mathbb Q)$ and find $r$ independent points. Given this information and a prime $p$ of good reduction, one can determine the space of regular 1-forms $\omega$ over ${\mathbb Q}_p$ on $X$ that kill $J(\mathbb Q)$
under the Chabauty-Coleman pairing to any desired $p$-adic precision.
In particular, one can compute the image of this space in the 1-forms
mod $p$. If $p > 2$ and there is such a 1-form mod $p$ that does not
vanish at any ${\mathbb F}_p$-point of $X$ (which heuristically happens
for a set of primes $p$ of positive density), then one can show
that each residue class mod $p$ can contain
at most one rational point. So we now just have to decide, for each
residue class, whether there is a rational point or not.
If there is a point, then we will eventually find it by searching for it.
If there is no point, then (again heuristically) we should be able
to prove this using the Mordell-Weil Sieve as explained in the paper.
Basically, one tries to use information obtained from reduction modulo
a bunch of further primes $q$, together with the knowledge of a
finite-index subgroup of $J(\mathbb Q)$, to get a contradiction.

So when $X$ and $J$ satisfy

- finiteness of Sha (or BSD)
- there exist $p$ of good reduction and a "good" differential
  on $X$ mod $p$ that does not vanish in $X(\mathbb F_p)$
- the "main" conjecture of [this paper](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/schrift.html#AG16)

then the procedure outlined above will terminate and determine $X(\mathbb Q)$. Also, *if* the procedure terminates, then it will produce the
correct result. So for practical purposes, we can just use it and
hope that it finishes. I have implemented it for curves of genus 2
(with Jacobian of rank 1) over $\mathbb Q$ in [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/). It works very
well in practice, even though there is no proof so far that it will
always work.

Comment: Thank you! So, the method with zeroes of analytic function can not be made into an algorithm? Also, could you please give a reference on how finiteness of Sha implies computability of $J(\mathbb{Q})$, or I overlooked  it in your paper?

Comment: @Sasha 1) The problem with zeros of analytic functions is that you may not be able to detect multiple zeros with a finite amout of computation; this is why we pick a special kind of prime, for which there are only simple zeros. Also, you usually have zeros that do not come from rational points, so you need some additional method to show this (this is the role of the Mordell-Weil Sieve). [to be continued]

Comment: 2) That finiteness of Sha implies computability of $J(\mathbb Q)$ is a standard fact. At least in principle, one can compute the $n$-Selmer group $S_n(J)$ of $J$ for any $n \ge 2$. It contains an isomorphic image of $J(\mathbb Q)/n J(\mathbb Q)$ and the quotient is the $n$-torsion of Sha. So when Sha is finite, then for all sufficiently large prime $n$, $\#S_n(J) = n^r$, where $r$ is the rank of $J(\mathbb Q)$. On the other hand, one will find $r$ independent points in $J(\mathbb Q)$ by systematic search. ...

Comment: ... In practice, this is feasible for hyperelliptic curves with $n = 2$ and in a few other rather special cases. (For elliptic curves, it looks a bit better; if the coefficients of the defining equation are not too large, one can do $n = 2,3,4,8,9$.)

Comment: Sure, I understand that if we have a bound for $\# Sha$ then we can compute the rank. But in principle, how can I be sure that I picked sufficiently large $n$? Sha may contain $n$-torsion and I cannot detect which torsion in Selmer group came from $J(\mathbb{Q})$ and which from Sha. This is probably not a problem if I am for some reason sure that Chabauty method is applicable for my curve, beause I only need a bound for rank which I will eventually obtain for a large $n$. But what if I want to check whether method is applicable or not(i.e. to avoid false negative result)?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what is the problem with multiple and collateral zeroes. If I know that the Newton polygon starts with a slope $\lambda$, I can iteratively calculate the digits of the root with valuation $-\lambda$. This procedure has to terminate because the root I am looking for is actually rational, and I can detect then it terminates substituting the root in the equation of my curve and checking if I got zero. If this is not a collateral root, I will eventually get it. But if it is not, I will notice this because I would get results that are too far from zero[tbc]

Comment: Say, if equation of my curve has integral coefficients, and after computing $n$ digits and substituting, I get a result with valuation less than $n$, I know that this is not a root.Then I divide my series by $(x-root)$ and repeat until there are slopes $<-1$. After (order of zero of the form in the reduction)+1 steps I will be done by Coleman's bound. Where the problem with multiple roots occur?

Comment: To be clear, surely your algorithm is more effective in practice, I just want to understand if one can prove effective Mordell conjecture for cruves with $r<g$ by Coleman's methods.

Comment: Sha: Finding points gives you successively better lower bounds on the rank, computing Selmer group gives you upper bounds. When Sha is finite, the bounds will eventually agree, and then you know that $n$ is sufficiently large. Zeros: The functions are $p$-adic analytic functions, which you can only know to finite precision. How do you want to tell two simple, but very close zeros from a double zero? You would have to distinguish between (say) $t^2$ and $t^2+at^n$ without knowing a bound for $n$. Send me an email if you have further questions.